# Flatlist doesn't display data from firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-flatlist, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to display one item in the Flatlist but it's doesn't display anything. Even the items outside of Flatlist aren't displayed. I don't ussually use Class componets so maybe I have missed something?

```js
static navigationOption = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
          scannedkey: navigation.getParam("itemId", null)
        }
      }
     
   
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={ 
        productlist:[],

        
        } }
        
    async componentDidMount(scannedkey){
        
        firebase.database().ref(`product/${scannedkey}`).on(
          "value",
          (snapshot) => {
            var list = [];
            snapshot.forEach((child) => {
              list.push({
                key: child.key,
                title: child.title,
                //details: child.val().details,
                //price: child.val().price
              });
            });
        
            this.setState({ productlist: list });
          },
          (error) => console.error(error)
        );
    }
  componentWillUnmount() {
      if (this.valuelistener_) {
        this.valueRef_.off("value", this.valuelistener_)
      }}
    
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.productlist)
 return(
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <Text>Hey</Text>
      <Text>{this.state.productlist.title}</Text>
     </View>
 );}}
```

This is what Error I get :

```
Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info.
(Saw setTimeout with duration 392608ms)
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:117:10 in registerWarning
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:63:8 in warnImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:36:4 in console.warn
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:18:4 in warn
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:226:6 in setTimeout
at node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.esm.js:99:8 in MemoryStorage
```

I would be grateful if you help me find the solution on how to fix it.

Comment: Typo. You're setting `produclist` instead of `productlist`

Comment: @jnpdx fixed the typo still didn't work I also added what I've been getting from he console log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `on('value')` handler, you have a typo:

```js
this.setState({ produclist: list });
```

should be

```js
this.setState({ productlist: list });
```

The [`on(...)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#on) method also accepts an error handling callback which you should attach to so you get information on any Database errors:

```js
.on(
  "value",
  (snapshot) => {
    var list = [];
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      const childData = child.val();
      list.push({
        key: child.key,
        title: childData.title,
        //details: childData.details,
        //price: childData.price
      });
    });

    this.setState({ productlist: list });
  },
  (error) => console.error(error)
);
```

One more thing, the [`on(...)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#on) method returns a callback that you should use in `componentWillUnmount` so that your element is properly destroyed:

```js
componentDidMount(scannedkey) {
  this.valueRef_ = firebase
    .database()
    .ref(`product/${scannedkey}`);
  this.valuelistener_ = this.valueRef_
    .on("value", ...)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  if (this.valuelistener_) {
    this.valueRef_.off("value", this.valuelistener_)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you added what asked, but still it still doesn't display I guess it's might me of the Flatlist.

Comment: @MayWheather you still haven't attached the error handler to `on('value')` (as shown in this answer), this will likely show what your problem is.

Comment: Sorry I updated the code and also posted a message that I got.

Comment: @MayWheather The typo of `productlist` is back again.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out again. Now it's doesn't display the Error but it's still shows me that the array is empty and gives me a warning message.

Comment: I also tested the key it's shows me undefined. So I guess I'm going to try to make sure that they key passes through correctly.

Comment: I'm just going to form another question.